# Spring @WebFluxTest is loading @Component s

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a @WebFluxTest in spring to test my controllers.

```
@WebFluxTest(value = {MyController.class})
public class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyService service;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
         ...
    }
```

However, when I execute the test, I get a lot of: **org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException** for dependencies of @Component s. Meaning that, Spring is trying to find dependencies of @Component when it should ignore those.
I understand that if I use **@WebFluxTest**, spring should not scan the classpath for any **@Component**.

My **Application** class is only annotated with **@SpringBootApplication**.

What could I be missing here?

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

So, I know what was happening. Actually, the class that I had annotated with @Component was an implementation of a **WebFilter**, and if I check the filter configured for a WebFluxTest (WebFluxTypeExcludeFilter) it adds **WebFilter** to the include part.
That is why Spring was picking it up.

Comment: You should make your solution update into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I know what was happening. Actually, the class that I had annotated with @Component was an implementation of a WebFilter, and if I check the filter configured for a WebFluxTest (WebFluxTypeExcludeFilter) it adds WebFilter to the include part. That is why Spring was picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're getting could be exactly due to the annotation @WebFluxTest not loading your @Component classes. Could it be that your MyService is instantiating any object that has @Component? Maybe your MyController

Exemplifying, supposing your MyService is like that:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
    private final MyRepository repository;

    private final Env env;

    public void insert(...) {
        System.out.println(env.getApplicationName() + " random stuff");
        ...
    }
}
```

And your Env is annotated with @Component, you will get the same error (**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**) if you try to use any method from the Env class since it's null due to @MockBean in MyControllerTest.
The same goes for MyController if it's instantiating any @Component object

If that is the case, then in your MyControllerTest you could try adding **@Import(Env.class)** or even trying to use **when()** from mockito with a **.thenReturn()**

If all that doesn't work, could you please provide more info about your error log and service/controller classes?